# Strategies for vertically navigating long programs in Vim

Tags: navigation

I'm aware of many ways of jumping around a text file in Vim.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-`f`/`b`/`u`/`d`
- `<count>G`
- `<count>%`
- marks
- `{`,`}`

And several other ways.

How can I jump around efficiently in long file? Please include a bit of "user experience" reasoning.

Please limit suggestions or techniques for vertical navigation only.

Comment: I've removed the end bits calling for opinion, which is off-topic here. I've also simplified the description of motions in the question and formatted them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- `[m` and `]m` to navigate from one method to the next
- `[[` and `]]` to navigate from one class to the next

You can also fold the entire file with `zM` to see only the top objects (class and function) and then `zo` to see the methods of the selected class and finally `zR` to unfold all the folds.

You can use plugin that show the structure of your code like: [tagbar](https://github.com/preservim/tagbar)

Answer (score 1):

Tags and other related "jump here" (*e.g.*, `:help include-search`, `gf`, `gd`, `*`) commands are great, when set up correctly. Searching with `/`,`?` is similarly fast. Both give you great control and precision to reach related code.

The `:grep`, `:vimgrep`, `:make`, *etc.*, commands all populate the quickfix list (but can be made to populate the location list). This list can be navigated with a few commands, or browsed in a window, to quickly jump to "interesting" parts of the code.

Both the quickfix/location lists and tags may involve traversing more than the current file, but in practice that's well worth it. In many cases you can restrict to the current file.

I also recommending learning more about ranges; inputting a range with no command jumps to the first line in that range. Search and marks work, too, and using `:` is occasionally faster (typically when you already want to operate on that range and know the Ex command to do it).

Answer (score 0):

The one (visible) difference between the BSD and Linux coding styles is that the BSD coding style puts the function name into the first column:

```
int
getlastch(const char *arg, size_t len)
{
        return (len ? arg[len - 1] : -1);
}
```

In `vi(1)` you can then navigate to this with `/^getlastch` or probably even already just `/^getl`. For navigation between files, ctags are the traditional solution.